# Swift replace key value in array of dictionaries with nested dictionaries

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have swift dictionary [String: Any] which I store in UserDefauls as an array [[String: Any]]

what I want to do is replace key: value with another one, e.g. `"id": "x:coredataid"`with`"id": "server id"`

I need to loop through array first and then through all key values. Is there any elegant solution for this purposes?

If not how then simple iterate through all key values and all nested levels in dictionary?

I have this code: `for (key, value) in params`

but it's only for top level keys.

Let me explain more in details. As you see I have `phases` key which an array. Also each `phase` contains `day` key which also an array.

So I don't care actually about key naming, phases it or days whether, what I want is to iterate all of key, values from provided [String: Any] dictionary and check if key contains a value which equal provided string.

As you see currently workoutId equals: `<x-coredata://C3C82F5A-8709-4EDC-8AE5-C23C65F220D5/WorkoutEntity/t072831FB-8F5C-4589-85CB-6D084671C097815>` I underscore it with red line.

[image]

So I want to loop a dictionary to catch this key workoutId and check if this equal `<x-coredata://C3C82F5A-8709-4EDC-8AE5-C23C65F220D5/WorkoutEntity/t072831FB-8F5C-4589-85CB-6D084671C097815>`

One more time I don't care about `workoutId` name, key can be actually named as `exerciseId` or id never mind. I just want to find a value `<x-coredata://C3C82F5A-8709-4EDC-8AE5-C23C65F220D5/WorkoutEntity/t072831FB-8F5C-4589-85CB-6D084671C097815>` in my entire dictionary and if there are lot of them replace all of them.

The reason why I need it is connected to identifier I store localy which are equals to CoreData identifiers as you my noticed. But when I modified my CoreData records with new identifiers returned from server I want to replace my UserDefaults off-line requests store with new ids.

I've added also modification to this code:

```
func update(_ dict: [String: Any], set serverId: Any, for localId: String) -> [String: Any] {
        var newDict = dict
        for (k, v) in newDict {
            if let mobileLocalId = v as? String {
                if mobileLocalId == localId {
                    newDict[k] = serverId
                } else { newDict[k] = v }
            } else if let subDict = v as? [String: Any] {
                newDict[k] = update(subDict, set: serverId, for: localId)
            } else if let dictionaries = v as? [[String: Any]] {
                for dictionary in dictionaries {
                    newDict[k] = update(dictionary, set: serverId, for: localId)
                }
            }
        }
        return newDict
    }
```

but it somehow drop days for me and newDict now looks like this:

```
(lldb) po newDict
▿ 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : "position"
    - value : 0
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : "workoutId"
    - value : "5d51723b3faceb53f9d2d5ed"
```

where actully I susscefully changed identifiers, but now all other key pairs from above example are missed.

Comment: A minimal example of an input & (desired) output would be really helpful.

Comment: Please add an example of input, and what you need as output. so we can offer more precise answer.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini I have modified question with more details. So the key feature I need is to iterate through ALL keys in dictionary, including nested array and replace a value if some key contains values I am trying to find.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution with a recursive function that replaces all values for a given key.

```
func update(_ dict: [String: Any], set value: Any, for key: String) -> [String: Any] {
    var newDict = dict
    for (k, v) in newDict {
        if k == key {
            newDict[k] = value
        } else if let subDict = v as? [String: Any] {
            newDict[k] = update(subDict, set: value, for: key)
        } else if let subArray = v as? [[String: Any]] {
            var newArray = [[String: Any]]()
            for item in subArray {
                newArray.append(update(item, set: value, for: key))
            }
            newDict[k] = newArray
        }
    }
    return newDict
}
```

Note that it doesn't check what type the existing value is but directly replaces it with the new value. Also the code assumes the only types of nested arrays are arrays of dictionaries.

For the array this function can be used with `map`

```
let out = data.map { update($0, set: "newValue", for: "id")}
```

Comment: Minor improvement: you should conditional cast and optional bind `v` instead of using `is` for the type-check and then force-casting it. `else if let subDict = v as? [String: Any] {
            newDict[k] = update(subDict, set: value, for: key)
        }`

Comment: yea also need to iterate through array then. can you update an answer how to do it with array as well. thank you! still no luck (

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander You asked about nested dictionaries and I answered, I am not going to adjust my answer every time you change your mind.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea agree, sorry about that, I just figured out about array just today, when tied your answers guys. It's my mistake regarding nested types as well.

Comment: I've add few lines of code and updated my question where I loop through array as well. So when I find needed value, looks like my code replace it, but somehow then I have 2 days instead of 7 which were provided before modification. thanks for answer anyway)

Comment: looks like forget else block `else { newDict[k] = v }`

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander So your arrays are only array of dictionaries? This was what was so annoying with your question earlier, without any sample data it felt that the structure could be any combination of object types.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea agree, I supposed it is should be minor question. The question is similar to finding all NSNull null in dictionary and replace them with provided value. But yea my arrays are arrays of [String: Any], I currently added if else where I loop through dictionaries, but function return for me non expected result with now. So now there are only 2 key pairs and no nested dictionaries at all=)

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander The problem with 2 vs 7 days is probably because you need to add the updated dictionary back to the array you are looping over

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I supposed it should be returned here `newDict[k] = update(dictionary, set: serverId, for: localId)`I provided details in updated question.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander As I mentioned, I have updated my answer to handle arrays correctly.

Comment: thanks so much!!! it was 2 hours battle) I just adopted it to check for values instead of key, as I need to replace actually searched value and never mind what they key is. as key could be named in a different way. like id, identifier, workoutId or water, because of server structure, thanks!)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson any way I can make this function under extension Dictionary? can you provide the example how it can be called?

Answer (score 3):

This recursive function will iterate through all key values:

```
func iterateThroughAllKeyValues<Key: Hashable, Value>(of dictionary: Dictionary<Key, Value>, execute execution: ((Key, Value))->()) {
    for element in dictionary {
        if let dictionary = element.value as? [Key: Value] {
            iterateThroughAllKeyValues(of: dictionary, execute: execution)
        } else {
            execution(element)
        }
    }
}
```

Also you can achieve calling `execution` on the main node of any nested dictionary with a little bit of change.

And this is the extension mode:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func iterateThroughAllKeyValues(execute execution: ((Key, Value))->()) {
        for element in self {
            if let dictionary = element.value as? [Key: Value] {
                dictionary.iterateThroughAllKeyValues(execute: execution)
            } else {
                execution(element)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: Careful about the order

Usage Example:

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = [
    "id0": "value0",
    "nested": ["id1": "value1"],
    "nestedNested": ["id2": "value2",
                     "nested": ["id3": "value3"]]
]

dictionary.iterateThroughAllKeyValues { (key, value) in
    print("key:", key, "Value:", value)
}
```

Output:

> key: id0 Value: value0
>
> key: id1 Value: value1
>
> key: id3 Value: value3
>
> key: id2 Value: value2

Comment: thanks for answer, but not sure how it using right, looks like with extantansion you've provided I can only access top level of dictionary (only main nodes) without jumping into nested dictionary. Here is my code. So I have 3 main node and one of them have more nested. But your extension only iterate throug 3 main, but I have more nested. I take a look at recursion and it looks good for me, not sure where is an issue.

Comment: What do you need exactly? this will go down to the last level.

Comment: ok let's say first node we get through iteration is a dictionary as well. so I need to jump into it and iterate through it as well and then return back to the next main node when we finished. looks like your are right it should work as you said with recursion, but somehow it does not. let me prepare a short video

thanks for help!!

Comment: I add an example to answer. but let me know if you need further help.

Comment: thanks! looks l've figured out, it's because a value I get back is wrapped into an array. I need to go through array as well. figure out while was recording a video: https://www.screencast.com/t/nHGAX6N8

Comment: Good to know. Unfortunately this video needs flash player, and the latest flash player is below my operating system Catalina 10.15 (latest version supports up to 10.14).

Comment: actually let's save I have a dictionary like a string and I want to quick lookup for all strings and replace them, that's was my initial idea.