# how to call function with parameter under extension Dictionary in swift5

Tags: swift, swift5

I have see function to update all value in dictionary credit to [Swift replace key value in array of dictionaries with nested dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57453254/swift-replace-key-value-in-array-of-dictionaries-with-nested-dictionaries)
but how can I make this `update` function as part of `extension Dictionary`? and how can I call the function if I place the function under `extension Dictionary`?

```
func update(_ dict: [String: Any], set value: Any, for key: String) -> [String: Any] {
    var newDict = dict
    for (k, v) in newDict {
        if k == key {
            newDict[k] = value
        } else if let subDict = v as? [String: Any] {
            newDict[k] = update(subDict, set: value, for: key)
        } else if let subArray = v as? [[String: Any]] {
            var newArray = [[String: Any]]()
            for item in subArray {
                newArray.append(update(item, set: value, for: key))
            }
            newDict[k] = newArray
        }
    }
    return newDict
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not check if the function itself works, I just transformed it so it is an extension of a `[String: Any]` dictionary.
It can be used like this : `newDictionary = yourDictionary.update(set: yourValue, for: yourKey)`.

```swift
extension [String: Any]
{
    func update(set value: Any, for key: String) -> [String: Any]
    {
        var newDict = self
        for (k, v) in newDict {
            if k == key {
                newDict[k] = value
            } else if let subDict = v as? [String: Any] {
                newDict[k] = subDict.update(set: value, for: key)
            } else if let subArray = v as? [[String: Any]] {
                var newArray = [[String: Any]]()
                for item in subArray {
                    newArray.append(item.update(set: value, for: key))
                }
                newDict[k] = newArray
            }
        }
        return newDict
    }
}
```

To be complete, you could probably also write a function to update your dictionary in place, which would use a bit less memory (untested) :

```swift
extension [String: Any]
{
    mutating func update(set value: Any, for key: String)
    {
        if self[key] != nil
        {
            self[key] = value
        }
        
        
        for (k, v) in self {
            if v is [String: Any]
            {
                var v = v as! [String: Any]
                v.update(set: value, for: key)
                self[k] = v
            }
            else if v is [[String: Any]]
            {
                var newV = [[String: Any]]()
                for array in v as! [[String: Any]]
                {
                    var array = array
                    array.update(set: value, for: key)
                    newV.append(array)
                }
                self[k] = newV
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this : `yourDictionary.update(set: yourValue, for: yourKey)`

Comment: what is difference between `extension [String: Any]` and `extension Dictionary`

Comment: Well, `extension Dictionary` would be an extension to any type of dictionary (eg. `[Int:String]`, `[String: Window]`, or whatever), when `extension [String:Any]` only apply for dictionary of this type, and cannot be used with other types of dictionary.
To create an `extension Dictionary`, you will consider in your code that keys are of type `Key`, and values of type `Value`, and the extension will apply to any dictionary.